# Font color in XeLaTeX tables

Tags: fonts, xetex

I defined the font and color of my text in the document preamble with the commands

```
\setmainfont{ConduMoveReg.otf}
\setmathfont{ConduMoveReg.otf}
\definecolor{darkblue}{cmyk}{1.00, 0.50, 0.00, 0.40}
\color{darkblue}
```

All my text, tables, and equations have the custom font I want, but only the normal text and equations are dark blue. My table's font and lines still black. Even if I change the color for red, for example, the table remains black. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should as LaTeX questions on http://s.tk/tex.

Comment: You should make a small complete example (with a standard font available on every system) that demonstrates your problem. Code snippets are in general useless.

Comment: I solved my problem. I put another

    \color{darkblue}

after the

    \begin{table}

Now I have caption, lines, and text, all in dark blue.

Answer (score 3):

This way you could set the desired color globally in your preamble, also valid for tables:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\color{darkblue}\global\let\default@color\current@color}
\makeatother
```

If you just mean tables in addition, you could redefine the table environment to get all lines and text such as captions in the desired color, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{cmyk}{1.00, 0.50, 0.00, 0.40}
\let\originaltable\table
\let\endoriginaltable\endtable
\renewenvironment{table}[1][ht]{%
  \originaltable[#1]
  \color{darkblue}}%
  {\endoriginaltable}   
\begin{document}
\color{darkblue}
text
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    1 \\\hline
    2 \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Test table}
\end{table}
\end{document}​
```

So you need to do it just once in your preamble, and if you decide to change the color later you can adjust it at this single place. Also, you could include `\centering` in this redefinition if you center all tables.